# How to use crane flatten from https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry?

Tags: docker

What is the correct syntax? Can it work with a local image?

Any have success except bitnami? =)

I'm trying to do

```
crane flatten saibaneko/bookworm-chaos:23.10 -t saibaneko/bookworm-chaos:23.10-flatten
```

And I got it

```
2024/02/08 23:19:13 flattening saibaneko/bookworm-chaos:23.10: pulling saibaneko/bookworm-chaos:23.10: GET https://index.docker.io/v2/saibaneko/bookworm-chaos/manifests/23.10: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:saibaneko/bookworm-chaos Type:repository]]
```

Comment: Does this help you ? [GitHub Issue](https://github.com/google/go-containerregistry/issues/1617). It looks like you need to add credentials t oyour config

Comment: I want to compress a local image, why should I use credentials to a remote registry?